# Servlet Example of using different log4j2-{env:envValue}.xml

Tags: servlets, config, log4j2, servletcontextlistener

Based on the answers in this thread "Defining different log4j2.xml configurations based on environment", from log4j user list I am trying to test using a different config for different environments. I tried posting to that list, but it doesn't seem to be accepting the e-mail questions, so posting here

This is what I have done.

- I have defined a Windows env variable websphere_environment and set its value to "local"
- My web.xml context-param looks like below - My servlet version is 3.0

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j2-${env:websphere_environment}.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```
- My relevant servlet method looks like below

  ```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
      ServletException, IOException {

      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServletLog4j2Test.class.getName());
      logger.fatal("Loaded:);
      //    " + /WEB-INF/config/log4j2-${env:websphere_environment}.xml
  }
  ```
- I do not have the lo4j2-local.xml defined in the WEB-INF/config ( it is defined as log4j-local.xml, not log4j2-local.xml and was expecting to get an error but it seems that the servlet is using a default configuration, because when I run the servlet, I get

  ```
  "07/24/14 07:14:07:564:FATAL:WebContainer : 0:        :     :com.test.log4j2.ServletLog4j2Test: Loaded:"
  ```
- How should my web-app and config files be set-up so that I can use different configs for different environments based on the environment?
- In this case, should I define a ServletContextListener to load the appropriate file?
- In that case my other question would be - when does a ServletContextListener get invoked?  Would the set-up be applied to everything in the web-app if defined in ServletContextListener?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Remko on the Log4j2 bugs list and the issue was resolved with Remko and Matt's help. Here are the   [details](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/LOG4J2-747) .

I had to make sure that I add the log4j2-web-x.jar file in the project and also needed to make sure I did not add the log4j2-web-x-sources.jar in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The log4j2 manual [configuration page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) describes what configuration files log4j2 will look for and where. If it cannot find a config file it will activate a default config that logs ERROR level events to the console.

The reason why your config file is not found is because of the variable in the file name `log4j2-${env:websphere_environment}.xml`.

You can use such variables *in your configuration file itself*, but not when specifying a path to the configuration file.

Comment: Thank you Remko. So, it is not possible to have different configuration files based on environment as we did in logj ( 1.x )? According to [Defining different log4j2.xml configurations based on environment](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Defining-different-log4j2-xml-configurations-based-on-environment-tp40639p40662.html) , I thought that was possible.  The only thing I thought I may have done wrong was configuration set-up.   Also, do you know, if I could use the ServletContextListener?

Comment: Oops, looks like I was wrong then.  If Ralph says it's supported but you can't get it to work then perhaps it was accidentally broken.  Can you raise a ticket for this on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker? By the way, have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: Sure I can. But pardon my ignorance. I need information what do I do when I am at  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel.  Could you help with it?

Comment: I have not tried the absolute path yet. I shall try it and post the result. What would be the syntax for absolute path? file:///C:\path-to-log4j-local.xml or the syntax is different from this?

Comment: You need to log in/register before you can create a ticket. Then you will get email when someone comments on your issue or changes the status etc. About the path format, not sure. Your url looks good at first glance.

Comment: Jira created - Log4j 2LOG4J2-747